# Implementing dijkstra's algorithm into windows form chart control

Tags: c#, algorithm, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to implements a dijkstra's model of finding the shortest path of a connected graph.
What I have is a graph that, upon hitting a button, randomly generates nodes on the graph.

What I would like to do is the following:

1. Determine if the graph is connected or not
2. if connected, then decide 1 of three different ways of finding the shortest path:
   a. Shortest path by distance between start and end node
   b. Shortest path by number of edges
   c. Shortest path by total weight of edges (here, less weight is what we want...)

Some other notes.

Because these DataPoints are randomly generated in this chartcontrol, I don't actually have a Vertex class to generate the vertices.  I've been searching around and see that most path finding functions utilize a vertex class.  So basically my list is going to get populated from nodes off of the chart control.

Could anyone provide any sort of insight in how I might go about solving the two above questions?

```
    //TODO:  Change to a function with return bool.  Void for purposes of testing at the moment.
    public void isConnected()
    {

        List<DataPoint> ParentPoints = new List<DataPoint>();

        //Gather all the non data generator into the same point array
        foreach (DataPoint pNonDG in chtGraph.Series[0].Points)
        {
            ParentPoints.Add(pNonDG);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more clear with your data types that you are using?

Comment: Right now all that I have is DataPoint really.  However, I can convert these to "Point" type.  Once done I can further convert the point coordinates to integers, floats, whatever I need to.  I haven't built any other class for this, as I figure if I need to get the data of a node, I can just look into the chart control series to find a point.  I'm also a pretty amateur programmer so sometimes I get lost in what I'm doing :)

Comment: Are you willing to make your own data types?

Comment: Yes, I am.  Seems like right now I'm not going down the right path :(

Answer (score 0):

A compute science graph is not the same as a "chart" graph that we made in statistics or math. A graph in computer science is a collection of "nodes" that are connected via a series of "edges"

A node is connected via an edge, but that doesn't mean it is connected back. Some edges can be one-way connections.

Edges often have "weights" or "costs" associated with them. This is where your dijkstra's algorithm will come in handy. It will use this costs to compute the shortest path to the target.

Lets look at some of the data types that we might employ

```
class GraphNode {
    List<GraphEdge> Edges = new List<GraphEdge>();
    public void AddEdge(GraphEdge edge) {
        Edges.Add(edge);
    }
    //you get the idea, this should have much more
    //it also manages edge connections
}

class GraphEdge { //this is a one way connection
    GraphNode ConnectedTo = null;
    //GraphNode ConnectedFrom = null; //if you uncomment this, it can be a two-way
                                      //connection, but you will need more code to
                                      //manage it
    float Cost = 0f;
    //you might consider adding a destructor that clears the pointers
    //otherwise gc might have a hard time getting rid of the nodes
}

class Graph {
    List<GraphNodes> Nodes = new List<GraphNodes>();
    //this class manages the nodes
    //it also provides help for connecting nodes
}
```